# How do I get magento admin email programmatically?

Tags: php, email, magento, admin, config

How do I get magento admin email programmatically?

From anywhere, so I'm looking for an answer that starts "Mage::"

Comment: Huh? That doesn't really make sense...

Comment: ofcourse you will get it programatically ;)

Comment: Who the hell says it doesnt make sense? its stupid to think that way

Comment: @BenM "programmatically" means, as opposed to opening up the user-interface and looking in the admin email section.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

The magento admin email is available via:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/value') ? 
    Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/value') : 
    Mage::getSingleton('core/config')->init()->getXpath('/config/default/trans_email/ident_general/email');
```

If you look at the html input elements in the backend config screen at system -> configuration -> store email addresses, you can see they are all named something like groups[ident_support][fields][email][value]. To get the value for any of these, just replace the ident_general in the getstoreconfig function above with ident_support or whatever is in the first square brackets.

Not sure if this is right, but it seems to work - leave an answer please if you have a better idea!